# fixing strict XHTML validation

Tags: xhtml

So looking around to see if I could find the answer before posting but  can't find any or I'm overlooking it but I tried validating an XHTML 1.0 Strict document. In the HTML code I have:

```
<a href="index.html" title="Return to Vining's Showcase Website Homepage" target="_blank"><span id="return">RETURN</span></a>
```

So, when I put the document through the validator, it says " there is no attribute "target"" and it gives an explanation of ". . . . you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead . . ." Though I'm willing to change the document type to "Transitional," but I'm more intrigued with the latter and wish to know how i can achieve this . . .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Validator instructions are quite clear I think. Opening in a new window is not possible with pure xhtml strict, only in xhtml transitional.
You could use JavaScript instead.

The other possibility mentioned aims for [this CSS3 property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp) i guess, which doesn't seem to work yet and is just some JavaScript replacement anyways.

But imho if you use CSS3 you don't need *xhtml strict* either, because a browser that can handle CSS3 is more than likely to also handle newer doctypes like html5.

/edit: Note that the thing with "marginheight" is just an example from the standard-errormessage which appears for several different problems.

Comment: Oh, okay. Think I'll use Transitional. Don't have time to insert JavaScript but thanks anyways.

Comment: Or XHTML5. Just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` if possible.

Comment: Could you then please mark my answer as solution? I need the points to have the right for voting :-)
And also sorry for writing this as a comment... I'm new and couldn't figure out how to write private messages yet (seems impossible on stackoverflow).
thanks

Comment: @Stony That's right, there are no private messages on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use XHTML5, you get the benefit of HTML5 elements along with the benefits of using the XML parser so just use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` as Mr Lister mentioned in his comment. My website / platform uses XHTML5 so if you're curious how the syntax *should* look either ask and/or visit the link in my profile. :-)